# Conditional statement on declaring global const variable Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm using a private SDK I can only declare one const global variable called

const unsigned char KitApplicationKey[]= {0x1b,0 etc.}

I would like to check one condition (a bool variable that i save in user default in the appdelagate) and modify the KitApplicationKey depending on the bool value

Something like that

dash if mybool true (I don't know how to write that)

const unsigned char KitApplicationKey[]= {0x1b,0 etc.}
dash  else
const unsigned char KitApplicationKey[]= {0x2C,0x1b etc.}
dash    endif

Can you please help me

Thank you

Comment: You can't change the values of a `const char []`. Can you elaborate on what your larger goal is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the value of a `const char []`. If you really need this, you might want to use a simple function instead to switch between the two values:

```
const unsigned char appKey1[]= {0x1b, 0x0};
const unsigned char appKey2[]= {0x2c, 0x1b};

char* appKey() {
    return myBool ? appKey1 : appKey2;
}
```

Obviously, you'll need to modify that for your own purposes to integrate it in your code, but otherwise, that should work just fine.